# VSTS build. Error - The job running on agent has exceeded the maximum execution time of 60

Tags: azure-pipelines

During build execution in `VSTS` I've got the next error:

> Job issue - 1 error
>
> The job running on agent has exceeded the maximum execution
>   time of 60.

**My question:**
How to increase `the maximum execution time` for build?

I did search in the internet, but didn't find solution.

Check screenshot with issue below:
[image: issue with build]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to go on `Edit` page of your build definition.
2. Then on tab `Options`.
3. Increase value for `Build job timeout in minutes`.

**Note:** An empty or zero value indicates an infinite timeout.

Check screenshot below:
[image: VSTS Build job timeout in minutes option]